# Determining the current element is the last element of a collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a better way to find if the current element of a collection is the last element?

```
@oranges = Orange.all

@oranges.each_with_index do |o, current_index|
  puts @oranges.size == (current_index + 1) ? "Last element!" : "Get next element"
end
```

OR

```
@oranges.each do |o|
  puts @oranges.last == o ? "Last element!" : "Get next element"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either looks fine, however if you were seriously considered about the perforamnce, I ran some benchmarks:

```
require 'benchmark'
a = (1..1000).to_a

def first(a)
  a.each_with_index do |o,i|
    a.size == (i + 1)
  end
end

def first_cached(a)
  a_size = a.size
  a.each_with_index do |o,i|
    a_size == (i + 1)
  end
end

def second(a)
  a.each do |e|
    a.last == e
  end
end

def second_cached(a)
  a_last = a.last
  a.each do |e|
    a_last == e
  end
end

Benchmark.bm(7) do |x|
x.report("first") {10000.times {first(a)}}
x.report("first_cached") {10000.times{first_cached(a)}}
x.report("second") {10000.times{second(a)}}
x.report("second_cached") {10000.times{second_cached(a)}}
end
```

which returned:

```
             user     system      total        real
first    2.020000   0.010000   2.030000 (  2.024102)
first_cached  1.930000   0.000000   1.930000 (  1.947230)
second   1.920000   0.010000   1.930000 (  1.922338)
second_cached  1.350000   0.000000   1.350000 (  1.352786)
```

So the second version, with a cached size yielded better results... however if these micro performances don't matter, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: If I could vote you an additional point for effort I would! Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 1):

Does the first solution even work? `o` is an orange and it doesn't have the `size` method.

You can instead do :

```
@oranges.each_with_index do |o, current_index|
  puts current_index == @oranges.size - 1 ? "Last element!" : "Get next element"
end
```

Apart from that both of the approaches are fine.